# is it bad practice to rename computers in the domain?

Tags: active-directory

in some of our Work routines.

IT supporters will eventually take a device that has been prepared for 'unnamed user' then when 'Peter' is hired.. he will rename it 'win10peter01'  that is our naming convention. I can't change that so no bother discussion it'.

Now a colleague is saying, that the IT supporters should first remove the device from the domain, then rename it, then join the domain again.
because renaming computers that are in the domain causes issues.
Another guy has a different opinion, and says it will not cause issues.

then a discussion of best practice started.

can you help us out?

Answer (score 3):

The names are only there to make the work easier for puny humans. The DC identifies objects by their SID.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming this is AD, you only need to remove and add a Domain Controller when you need to rename it. A regular domain client / server can be safely renamed.

If your using the CLI [Netdom](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc788029(v=ws.11).aspx)